# Write an application that determines whether a Sudoku square is valid

Tags: c#, visual-studio, matrix, boolean, sudoku

Write an application that determines whether a Sudoku square is valid. The code works well now.

Example:

**For input data:**

```
9 1 8  5 7 2  6 4 3
7 5 3  6 9 4  1 8 2
2 6 4  1 8 3  7 9 5

1 9 6  4 2 8  5 3 7
3 8 2  7 5 6  9 1 4
5 4 7  9 3 1  8 2 6

4 7 9  2 1 5  3 6 8
8 2 5  3 6 9  4 7 1
6 3 1  8 4 7  2 5 9
```

**The console will display:**

```
True
```

**Suggestion 1:**

The first step is to read the Sudoku square from the keyboard.

Note: You should allow blank lines and more than one space between the elements on a line of the square so that you can group the numbers in a more readable form (like the square format given as an example in the problem).

The program will return False if a line contains more or less than 9 elements, non-numeric values, numbers less than 1 or greater than 9.

After the complete shopping cart has been read we check that the entered configuration is valid. To do this we take each column, row and 3x3 block of the frame in turn and check that each element from 1 to 9 appears exactly once.

**Here is my code:**

```
using System;

namespace Sudoku
{
    class Program
    {
        const int SudokuBoardSize = 9;
        const int SudokuBlockSize = 3;

        static void Main()
        {
            byte[,] sudokuBoard = new byte[SudokuBoardSize, SudokuBoardSize];
            Console.WriteLine(ReadSudokuBoard(sudokuBoard) && IsValidSudokuBoard(sudokuBoard));
            Console.Read();
        }

        static bool IsValidSudokuBoard(byte[,] sudokuBoard)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < SudokuBoardSize; i++)
            {
                if (!IsValidSudokuItem(sudokuBoard, "line", i) ||
                    !IsValidSudokuItem(sudokuBoard, "column", i) ||
                    !IsValidSudokuItem(sudokuBoard, "block", i))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        static bool IsValidSudokuItem(byte[,] sudokuBoard, string itemType, int itemIndex)
        {
            byte[] sudokuValuesCount = new byte[SudokuBoardSize];

            for (int i = 0; i < SudokuBoardSize; i++)
            {
                byte sudokuValue = GetSudokuValue(sudokuBoard, itemType, itemIndex, i);
                sudokuValuesCount[sudokuValue - 1]++;
                if (sudokuValuesCount[sudokuValue - 1] > 1)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        static byte GetSudokuValue(byte[,] sudokuBoard, string itemType, int itemIndex, int position)
        {
            switch (itemType)
            {
                case "line":
                    return sudokuBoard[itemIndex, position];
                case "column":
                    return sudokuBoard[position, itemIndex];
                case "block":
                    int line = itemIndex / SudokuBlockSize * SudokuBlockSize + position / SudokuBlockSize;
                    int column = itemIndex % SudokuBlockSize * SudokuBlockSize + position % SudokuBlockSize;
                    return sudokuBoard[line, column];
            }

            return 0;
        }

        static bool ReadSudokuBoard(byte[,] sudokuBoard)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < SudokuBoardSize; i++)
            {
                string[] lineValues = ReadLineValues();
                if (lineValues.Length != SudokuBoardSize)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < SudokuBoardSize; j++)
                {
                    if (!IsValidSudokuValue(lineValues[j], out int value))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    sudokuBoard[i, j] = (byte)value;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        static string[] ReadLineValues()
        {
            string line;
            do
            {
                line = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            while (line == "");

            return line.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }

        static bool IsValidSudokuValue(string stringValue, out int value)
        {
            if (!int.TryParse(stringValue, out value))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (value < 1 || value > SudokuBoardSize)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Try posting a piece of code and say "I expected result A, why do I instead get result B?"

Comment: @SebDieBln How do I ignore spaces while reading the matrix?

Comment: @LaurențiuCozma easiest would probably be to use [`string.Replace(" ", "")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_) (notice, this simply replaces spaces with empty strings). You can do the same with any other whitespace (tabs and so on)

Comment: @RolandDeschain I am beginner, I do not know how to implement that in my code, can you help me please?

Comment: Currently your program is setup to read only a single number of the sudoku matrix for each entry. `Console.ReadLine()` will return a `string`. Now strings implement the `Replace()` function, which again returns the same string, but with the items replaced according to the `Replace()` function. Does this help?

Comment: Apart from that, it might be more intuitive to change the code, so that a user can enter complete rows of the SUDOKU matrix?

Comment: It does not really help

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT it does not work, I got an error "The name 'Regex' does not exist in this current context

Comment: @LaurențiuCozma You just need to add 'using System.Text.RegularExpressions;‘ in your project.

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT I added it. Now after I copy paste the matrix, I get this error "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'
"

Comment: @LaurențiuCozma My test result has no problem. You better copy my code in order to avoid entering extra spaces or other things. I will add a screenshot of the test results to my answer later.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to ignore spaces while reading the matrix, you can refer to the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] matrix = new int[9, 9];
        Console.WriteLine("input:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            string newstr = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s", "");
            if (newstr == "")
            { 
                i--;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                {
                    matrix[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(newstr[j]) - 48;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The following code can determine whether a Sudoku square is valid:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] matrix = new int[9, 9];
        Console.WriteLine("input:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            string newstr = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s", "");
            if (newstr == "")
            { 
                i--;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                {
                    matrix[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(newstr[j]) - 48;
                }
            }
        }
        if (isValidSudoku(matrix))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("True");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("False");
        }
    }
    static int N = 9;
    static bool isinRange(int[,] matrix)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                if (matrix[i, j] <= 0 ||matrix[i, j] > 9)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    static bool isValidSudoku(int[,] matrix)
    {
        if (isinRange(matrix) == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        bool[] unique = new bool[N + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            Array.Fill(unique, false);
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                int Z = matrix[i, j];
                if (unique[Z])
                {
                    return false;
                }
                unique[Z] = true;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            Array.Fill(unique, false);
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                int Z = matrix[j, i];
                if (unique[Z])
                {
                    return false;
                }
                unique[Z] = true;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < N - 2; i += 3)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N - 2; j += 3)
            {
                Array.Fill(unique, false);
                for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                {
                    for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
                    {
                        int X = i + k;
                        int Y = j + l;
                        int Z = matrix[X, Y];
                        if (unique[Z])
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                        unique[Z] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot of my test.

[image]

Comment: Something is wrong and I do not understand what, I copy paste  your code. Here is an image how it looks: https://imgur.com/a/APD56tE

Comment: Here is the code: https://codeshare.io/K8P9YK

Comment: I edited the code, please try again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code adapted to get rid of the whitespaces and take complete lines of the SUDOKU matrix as input:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    

    int[][] matrix = new int[9][];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Enter line {i}:");

        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        
        string input_removed_spaces = input.Replace(" ", "");
        // if you want to remove all whitespaces, you can use Regex for example:
        // input_removed_all_whitespaces = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s+", "");

        //Before setting the matrix, obviously you need additional checks, for example if the user enters invalid inputs
        matrix[i] = Array.ConvertAll(input_removed_spaces.ToCharArray(), c => (int)Char.GetNumericValue(c));
    }

    // do stuff with your matrix here
}
```

As written, you will have to implement additional checks (what if the user enters letters, nothing, to many numbers, ...) but this should get you started

Comment: It work how I want, but I still have 1 problem. How can I ignore blank spaces too? Because in my problem I have blank spaces too and it stops at line 9 which is the 7th with numbers of the matrix, because it takes the blank spaces too

Comment: Do you mean if the user simple presses enter without any input? This shouldn't be too hard, just check the `input` string and what it contains.

Comment: Yes, I mean that. Can you write it in your code, please? I am a beginner and I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Sorry, but that isn't how this site works. If you have any questions, I'm happy to help, but it is not a code writing service.